# SQL Server PDO-ODBC Connection UTF-8

Tags: php, sql-server, utf-8, pdo, odbc

I'm trying to connect to Microsofts SQL Server (2000 & 2008) via PHP (5.5) on Windows with PDO_ODBC and set the Charset to UTF-8, but I don't find a way. That's what I'm trying:

```
$db['conn'] = new PDO(

    //"odbc:driver={SQL Server};".
    "odbc:driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};".
    //"odbc:driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};".

    "server=".$db['host'].";".
    "database=".$db['bank'].";".
    "uid=".$db['user'].";".
    "pwd=".$db['pass'].";".
    "charset=UTF-8;"
);
```

With PDO_SQLSRV it works by default. But since there isn't an official PDO_SQLSRV driver for PHP 5.5 and I have to connect to an old SQL Server 2000, I can't use PDO_SQLSRV.

Is there an option I can use while I'm connecting via PDO_ODBC? 
I search a way to avoid an PHP utf8_encode().

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There are unofficial compilations for PHP/5.5. The problem with ODBC is that encoding cannot be set in code—you need to tweak some ODBC configuration file. (And please remember that `utf8_encode()` converts from ISO-8859-1.)

Comment: Unfortunatly the official PHP 5.4 and unofficial PHP 5.5 pdo_sqlsrv drivers dropped SQL Server 200 support (what's correct since microsoft dropped sql server 200 supper last summer). Can I tweak a ODBC configuration file on windows? Yu're right ... mb_convert_encoding() from cp1252 to utf8 will provide an better result ;)